# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED after EC2 reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, singlestore

I have a memsql server running on AWS and decided to upgrade the instance type for better performance. In order to upgrade an EC2 server though you must first shut it down, then perform the upgrade and then start it up again.

My server was working absolutely fine when I was connecting to it from my Node API but since the reboot/ instance upgrade I am getting the following message:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I have not changed any of the connection configuration in my node API and I am able to SSH into the memsql server using the same IP address as I had before the instance upgrade.

Is there anything funny that AWS EC2 may do when you reboot such as changing ports for example that would cause me to get this error?

Am really stuck so not sure where to begin

Comment: Have you checked your SecurityGroups for IP-based rules?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a ECONNREFUSED with a badly configured SG, but just to be sure.

Comment: Check whether MemSQL is running normally by either `memsql-admin list-nodes` or `memsql-ops memsql-list` depending on how you installed MemSQL. If MemSQL is online, try connecting to it directly from localhost. If it's offline, check the tracelogs/memsql.log.

Comment: you can also give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/77072069/12098728.